# Are there any class-changing prefixes in English?

Tags: parts-of-speech, prefixes, derivational-morphology, affixes

Whenever I do a Google search about affixes, I find information like 'Prefixes usually do not change the class of the base word, but suffixes usually do change the class of the word' ([UEfAP](http://www.uefap.com/writing/feature/complex_lexcomp.htm)).

As I understand there are some class-changing prefixes in English. However, when I tried to find at least one example, I always fail. Could you give me an example like **'class-changing prefix + its stem'**?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*en-*:

noun to verb: *encourage, endanger, engulf, enthrone, entomb*

adjective to verb: *endear, enfeeble, enrich, ensure*

*de-*:

noun to verb: *debone, defang, de(-)ice*

Answer (score 42):

Yes, there are a few derivational prefixes whose application does change
the base word class (part of speech, syntactic category) to a different
derived word class.

| Prefix | Base class | Derived class | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| en‑ | noun | verb | *encase, encode, enslave, entomb, enveil, envenon* |
| en‑ | adjective | verb | *enable, enfeeble, enlarge, endear, enrich* |
| em‑ | noun | verb | *embalm, embattle, embed, empanel, emplace, empower* |
| em‑ | adjective | verb | *embitter* |
| e‑ | noun | verb | *elapse* |
| a‑ | noun | adverb | *abloom, aboard, abreast, across, afield, akin* |
| a‑ | adjective | adverb | *afresh, afoul, around, astray, awry* |
| be‑ | noun | verb | *befriend, bewitch, bedevil* |
| be‑ | adjective | verb | *becalm, belittle* |
| de‑ | noun | verb | *debrief, decamp, defraud, delouse, deplane, dethrone* |
| un‑ | noun | verb | *uncloak, unhorse, unman, unmask, unseat, unveil* |
| up‑ | noun | adverb | *upstage, upstairs, upwind* |
| down‑ | noun | verb | *downscale, downsize* |

The first two, *en‑* and *em‑*, are of course different spellings of the same prefix.

I can't offhand think
of any examples for its *el‑* or *er‑* spellings — at least, not ones which occurred within English.

Consider also: *outdate, outlaw, outside; inflame, imperil*.

Comment: Probably the most common derivational affix is Zero. It [verbs nouns in several different ways](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Verbing.pdf).

Comment: In the case of _de-_ and _un-_, aren't most of the words to which they're affixed already verbs? (You can seat someone, just as you can unseat them; you can be briefed as well as debriefed; and so on.)

Comment: Does en- have commonly used el- or er- spellings at all? Although English generally avoids using  inl- and inr- in words taken from Latin, the sequences enl- and enr- are not similarly avoided (either in English, or in French, where many *en-* words come from).

Comment: *Be* also makes prepositions out of other classes: *below*, *beside*, *behind*.

Comment: I would argue that the e- and em- prefixes are just euphony forms of en-. Notice that e- only appears in one word, and em- only appears with roots that begin with _b_ or _p_.

Comment: @AndrewRay: The "e-" in  "elapse" is a Latin variant of the prepositional prefix *ex-.* Other words containing it are *elicit, elide, elect, elongate, eliminate*; *eradicate, erect, erode*; *evacuate, evade, eviscerate, evoke.*

Comment: New York Times crossword is extremely fond of that that *a-* prefix...

Comment: @JohnLawler Would zero be considered specifically a _prefix_, though? Given that it interacts with endings (e.g., when deriving from an irregular verb or noun, the resulting noun or verb is always regular, arguably due to the presence of the zero-derivation sememe), I’ve always thought of it as being, if anything, suffixal in nature.

Comment: Zero means the absence of any affix, so no, it couldn't be considered a prefix or a suffix. But it does the job of an affix; probly this is just one minor stage in the revision of the morphology. Most affixes in English, and all the few inflectional ones, are suffixes. But we've still got a few prefixes, all derivational. Since English POS are so fluid, "changing" them is usually more a matter of use in a different syntactic frame than the addition or subtraction of affixes. English is pretty analytic any more.

Comment: The "up" and "down" examples feel more like compound words that happen to have a different class than their second word than they do prefixes that are changing the class.